# Excel Vba column with unique date value to array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

How to save the a column of values into array with the column is in datetime format and i need to get only the unique values in to the array by omiting the time. that is i need to compare only the date.

```html
1/1/2014 9:30
1/1/2014 14:03
1/1/2014 9:56
1/1/2014 9:57
1/1/2014 11:11
1/1/2014 16:45
1/1/2014 12:31
1/1/2014 14:04
1/1/2014 15:16
1/1/2014 14:10
1/1/2014 14:17
1/1/2014 14:52
1/1/2014 16:26
1/1/2014 17:08
1/1/2014 17:00
1/1/2014 17:44
1/1/2014 17:41
1/1/2014 18:32
1/1/2014 19:00
1/1/2014 21:06
1/1/2014 19:37
1/1/2014 19:22
1/1/2014 23:08
1/2/2014 0:30
1/2/2014 1:57
1/2/2014 5:16
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If without VBA, then Text to Columns with space as the delimiter and create a PivotTable with ColumnA for ROWS.